# Timer in Thread

Tags: java

I’m working on the task of monitoring the execution of query, it became necessary to check the query after a certain time. Please, help me, how to implement the method poll correctly? Is it possible to do this in a separate thread? For example, I want to log every iteration of the loop and end the stream on the number 8. how to implement it correctly? Thanks!

```
public class MyTimerTask implements Runnable {

    String name;
    private boolean isActive;

    void disable(){
        isActive=false;
    }

    MyTimerTask(String name){
        isActive = true;
        this.name = name;
        run();
    }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                System.out.println(name + " Start at :" + new Date());
                try {
                    completeTask();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(name + " Finish at:" + new Date());

        }
        private void completeTask() throws InterruptedException {
                 for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                     System.out.println(i);
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                 }
        }


        public static void main(String args[]){

            new MyTimerTask("device");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that a sleep-based time is inaccurate, `sleep(1000)` may sleep a couple of millis more if it feels like. Also, I would suggest a `ScheduledExecutorService` with `scheduleAtFixedRate` instead. And please do not use the old legacy class `Date`, use the replacement classes in `java.time`, `LocalDate` for example. Note that your `isActive` field needs to be `volatile`, otherwise other threads might not see the correct value. You can also realize a stop-feature using `interrupt()`. All in all, your code feels very old. Modern Java has a lot of nice thinks for you to make this simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class MyTimerTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " Start at :" + new Date());
        completeTask();
        System.out.println(name + " Finish at:" + new Date());
    }

    private void completeTask() throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Thread(new MyTimerTask(), "device").start();
    }
}
```

- Do not need those fields, `java.lang.Thread` have those.
- Do not call methods from the constructor that requires the instance to be fully created. EG: do not call `run()` from it.
- `InterruptedException`s should be caught, but in this case you may want to swallow it, as it is not signalling an unfinished job...
- To create a new thread use the `Thread`: You can specify the `Runnable` instance and/or name as arguments of the constructor. Or you can extend it and call `super()` with the name in the constructor, and implement `run()` in it.

.

```
public class MyTimerTask extends Thread {

    public MyTimerTask() {
        super("device");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " Start at :" + new Date());
        completeTask();
        System.out.println(name + " Finish at:" + new Date());
    }

    private void completeTask() throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Thread().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You implementation works fine.
You just need include on main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Thread(new MyTimerTask("device")).start();
}
```

Have in mind that according this implementation you'll run the function only 10 times.
As you have a status flag maybe you can use it changing the loop intructoin.

```
 while (isActive) {
        System.out.println(name + " Start at :" + Instant.now());
```